# Find the value of y according to condition:

Tags: c++11

Find the value of y according to condition:

[image]

**I tried to do but something is wrong or I did not right so I need some help**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x, y;

int main() {
  scanf("%d", &x);
  if (x < 5)
    y = x * x - 3 * x + 4;
  else
    y = x + 7;
  printf("%d", y);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: to write the code of that condition. I'm a beginner in c++ so i may do something not right

Comment: Try typing the condition in text. You need an `else if` condition. Also, this is a C question, not C++11. If that is what you use, you can use `cout` and `cin` instead of `printf` & `scanf`.

Comment: `if (x < -4) y = x + 5; else if ...`

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if (x<-4) {
  y=x+5;
} else if (x>=-4 && x<=7) {
  y=x*x-3*x;
} else {
  y=x*x*x+2*x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your piece-wise function has 3 segments in its domain. You have to divide you condition into three segments. Your syntax will be like this :

```
if(condition 1){
    <statement 1>
}
else if(condition 2){
    <statement 2>
}
else {
<statement 3>
}
```

Or you can use three 'if' statements to check the input value.

```
if(condition 1) {
<statement 1>
}
if(condition 2) {
<statement 2>
}
if(condition 3) {
<statement 3>
}
...
...
...
```

Hope you understand.